# I am getting this error "use of undeclared identifier 'recipe'

Tags: ios, xcode-6.2

Please refer to below code.

```
#import "RecipeDetail.h"
#import "Recipe.h"

@implementation RecipeDetail

@synthesize recipeLabel;
@synthesize recipeName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = recipe.name;
    self.prepTimeLabel.text = recipe.prepTime;
    self.recipePhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:recipe.imageFile];

    NSMutableString *ingredientText = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSString* ingredient in recipe.ingredients) {
        [ingredientText appendFormat:@"%@\n", ingredient];
    }
    self.ingredientTextView.text = ingredientText;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you alloc you class object in `viewDidLoad` method like this.

```
Recipe *recipe=[[Recipe alloc]init];
```

then after you can use recipe object like that.

```
self.title = recipe.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the **Correct** error.

The the variable **recipe** is undeclared and you are trying to assign values from a non-existing variable.

So, either you should declare it before using it in your `viewDidLoad` method like:

```
Recipe *recipe = [Recipe alloc] init];
```

and then use it.

Or if you want to pass an existing recipe variable from outside this class, as it appears that you are trying to do that, then where ever you are declaring and initializing an instance of this class **RecipeDetial** make a **Recipe** property in **RecipeDetail.h** like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Recipe *recipe;
```

and assign that variable to this property before presenting this `UIViewController` and use it as you are using it already.

Hope this helps...